# Torrents on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: server, bittorrent, transmission

I just configured several times a personal server Ubuntu Server 14.04. So I'm a beginner in this.

I want to download via torrents in specific folder into server. In order to use those file on Plex or other things. The goal is to use the server to download torrents in a folder.

Anyone can help me with some information ?

Thanks !

Comment: What torrent client?

Comment: Transmission has a web version that is perfect for this. Here is the official document https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo#Command_Line_Interface

Comment: and there is also a CLI version in the repositories (transmission-cli and transmission-remote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this with the `Deluge` torrent client.

Start Deluge, then `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Downloads` and choose your "Download to" folder on this screen.

Deluge can be installed from the software center or by `sudo apt-get install deluge-gtk`.  The first time you run `Deluge` I recommend doing `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Interface` and enable "Classic Mode" to simplify the interface, then restart `Deluge`.

Comment: Server... What you suggest is for him to install the desktop version to do this? The answer for deluge would be to install the web-ui version of deluge and use the browser for the maintenance.